# Disable Steam Guard email, but not phone guard?

Tags: steam

I feel like the texts are a much more secure way to get the code, rather than my email. Anyone can access my email but my phone is always with me.

I also dont like anyone having a chance to see my email or any part of it - even if it is just a few letters.

So basically, can I disable the email guard so my phone is the only way to get into my account and my phone is the only way?

Answer (score 1):

In the options of the SteamGuard, you can now activate de Authenticator on your phone via the Steam App.

Go to your Account Details/Account Security/Manage Steam Guard and chose the Authenticator option.
It is not exactly the same as getting a text instead of a mail but allow you to use your phone and not your email address to log in to Steam.